# App crashing only on AppStore reviewer's device during review phase. Can't replicate the crash nor can any of my TestFighters. Diagnosing with atos

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store, google-analytics-firebase

So I've been going back and forth now with the Apple reviewer trying to fix this crash that they are experiencing after a successful IAP in my app. I haven't been able to replicate it myself because all purchases wether they're successful or not work as intended for me, as well as all my friends that have tested this app over TestFlight.

The crash only happens for the reviewer when they purchase something and the successful purchase alert appears. Once they tap the "Ok" it appears to crash. It could be crashing when it appears but it seems more likely that it's crashing when it's dismissing, based on the crash log's stack trace later in this post.[image]

For reference I've used just plain StoreKit and SwiftyStoreKit to handle purchases trying to fix this because I thought I had messed up somewhere after just trying plain StoreKit, but they both still have the same crash.

The reviewer gave me the crash log back and I'm just starting to learn how to use the atos tool to understand whats going wrong. ChatGPT has told me that this part from the stack trace: `{"value":4335622920,"matchesCrashFrame":1}` is where it has crashed.

I then took that memory address and ran the atos command:

`atos -o "/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-07-31/myapp 7-31-23, 4.42 PM.xcarchive/dSYMs/myapp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/myapp" -arch arm64 -l 4335288320 4335622920`

and got the result:

`_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_PodsDummy_GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport (in myapp) + 93752`

I used Cocoapods to install all my additional libraries that are FirebaseAuth, FirebaseFirestore, IQKeyboardManager, FirebaseFirestoreSwift, Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK, and SwiftyStorekit so this leads me to believe that there are conflicting pods in my project even though I nor anyone else that has tested this has ever been able to replicate. I then tried removing the line `pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'` from my podfile (only one that I think is related to that) and then xcode throws me the error when trying to build:

`File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a`

Which makes no sense to me. I've tried it on both the simulator and a physical device too. I've been trying to symbolicate a few more things at the top of my stack trace that ChatGPT has flagged as a potential problem, with the commands:

`atos -o "/Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-07-31/SatStacker 7-31-23, 4.42 PM.xcarchive/dSYMs/SatStacker.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SatStacker" -arch arm64 -l 4335288320 8925373064`

`atos -o "/Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-07-31/SatStacker 7-31-23, 4.42 PM.xcarchive/dSYMs/SatStacker.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SatStacker" -arch arm64 -l 4335288320 6131576953`

But those just echoed the same address back and from what I've read that means it is  out of range of my apps memory so I cant see what it is. I've triple checked that the UUID of my app in the crash log matches my dSYM UUID that I generated with the command:

`dwarfdump --uuid "/Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-07-31/SatStacker 7-31-23, 4.42 PM.xcarchive/dSYMs/SatStacker.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SatStacker"`

For reference the function that I call to initiate the purchase takes in the bundleID from AppStoreConnect as a parameter like this:

```
func buyInAppPurchase(productID: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.delegate?.showSpinner()
        }
        
        SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(productID, quantity: 1, atomically: true) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let purchase):
                print("Purchase Success: \(purchase.productId)")
                self.validateReceipt { isValid in
                    if isValid {
                        self.delegate?.sendInfo(itemNum: self.itemNumber)
                    } else {
                        print("Receipt validation failed after purchase.")
                    }
                    self.itemNumber = 0  // Reset itemNumber here after handling the purchase
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.delegate?.hideSpinner()
                    }
                }
            case .error(let error):
                print("Purchase failed: \(error)")
                self.itemNumber = 0  // Reset itemNumber here after handling the error
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.hideSpinner()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Again, I haven't been able to replicate the crash myself and I'm trying to learn how to read this crash log, but a lot of this seems really strange/odd because it just seems like it should be working just fine.

Here's more of the stack trace for reference too:

```
"threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":3878218,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":1},{"value":1},{"value":8925373064,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"type metadata for Date"},{"value":6131576953},{"value":0},{"value":2976},{"value":1},{"value":3},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":10746840608},{"value":2684878849},{"value":845},{"value":4822103232},{"value":2043},{"value":8901477912,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject"},{"value":9056690256,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_platform_memmove"},{"value":8925321232},{"value":0},{"value":4862313952},{"value":0},{"value":8925373064,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"type metadata for Date"},{"value":10788848736},{"value":6131576944},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":4862314128},{"value":8925303232,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"value witness table for Builtin.Int64"},{"value":8850628608,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"OBJC_IVAR_$_UIPopoverController._originalArrowDirections"}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4335621548},"cpsr":{"value":1610616832},"fp":{"value":6131577408},"sp":{"value":6131576928},"esr":{"value":4060086273,"description":"(Breakpoint) brk 1"},"pc":{"value":4335622920,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":10212828596}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":334600,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":258640,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":226548,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":54412,"symbol":"-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]","symbolLocation":1236,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":4576128,"symbol":"-[UIViewController __viewWillDisappear:]","symbolLocation":96,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":7751708,"symbol":"__56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_3","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":3291668,"symbol":"+[UIPresentationController _scheduleTransition:]","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":3289360,"symbol":"-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]","symbolLocation":1564,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":7746456,"symbol":"-[UIPresentationController _dismissWithAnimationController:interactionController:target:didFinish:]","symbolLocation":400,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":3050576,"symbol":"-[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithAnimationController:interactionController:completion:]","symbolLocation":424,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":3147016,"symbol":"-[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:]","symbolLocation":1016,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":3145672,"symbol":"-[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:]","symbolLocation":1856,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":3143792,"symbol":"-[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:]","symbolLocation":396,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":4083800,"symbol":"-[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":15606216,"symbol":"__103-[UISheetPresentationController _startInteractiveTransitionWithProgress:fromViewController:completion:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":92,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":3408148,"symbol":"+[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitionsAllowingAnimation:actions:]","symbolLocation":140,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":15606064,"symbol":"-[UISheetPresentationController _startInteractiveTransitionWithProgress:fromViewController:completion:]","symbolLocation":292,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":1101580,"symbol":"-[UISheetPresentationController sheetInteraction:didChangeOffset:]","symbolLocation":1252,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":1100268,"symbol":"-[_UISheetInteraction sendCurrentOffsetDidChange]","symbolLocation":100,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":4033236,"symbol":"+[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocksPrivate) _modifyAnimationsWithPreferredFrameRateRange:updateReason:animations:]","symbolLocation":168,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":4033052,"symbol":"__86-[_UISheetInteraction draggingChangedInSource:withTranslation:velocity:animateChange:]_block_invoke_2","symbolLocation":152,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":2446820,"symbol":"-[UIViewPropertyAnimator _runAnimations]","symbolLocation":180,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":6100836,"symbol":"__49-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]_block_invoke_3","symbolLocation":68,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":2914764,"symbol":"__49-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":92,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":2445952,"symbol":"__49-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]_block_invoke_2","symbolLocation":224,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":2451676,"symbol":"-[UIViewPropertyAnimator _setupAnimationTracking:]","symbolLocation":100,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":2450728,"symbol":"-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]","symbolLocation":784,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":4491476,"symbol":"__86-[_UISheetInteraction draggingChangedInSource:withTranslation:velocity:animateChange:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":196,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":1985380,"symbol":"-[_UIHyperInteractor _interactionChangedMutatingTranslation:velocity:mutatingState:]","symbolLocation":152,"imageIndex":23},{"imageOffset":1983820,"symbol":"-[_UIHyperInteractor _interactionChangedCopyingTranslation:velocity:mutatingState:]","symbolLocation":156,"imageIndex":23},
```

Anyone know what to do in this situation? I'm really at a loss and have no idea what could be causing this crash.

Comment: The crash log would be infinitely more useful than what ChatGPT thinks is the issue. But more often than not I’ve seen that people forget to account for the odd scenarios such as no internet connection. Remove the store kit config file and put your devices on airplane mode then run your code also try on an iPad and as macCatalyst.

Comment: What I meant was I fed the crash log into ChatGPT because I'm not sure how to really read it yet. I think it identified the correct library that caused the crash in my stack trace.

Comment: Showing the decoded log or putting it in organizer and getting the exact line would be much better.

Comment: I'm not sure how or where to do that. I'm using the atos tool because I'm relying on the crashlog from the apple reviewer that they sent. Is there somewhere else that I can feed that crash log to?

Comment: I’m check the message it came in it usually has basic instructions or Google something like “Reading Apple Crash Log” you’ll find Apple’s documentation on the subject. More often than not it is very simple and Organizer gives you the answer.

Comment: I glanced over SwiftyStoreKit and discovered a few _potential_ threading issues (data races). It seems, the API is implicitly confined to the main thread, but yet internally changes variables on delegate methods which are documented not to be called on any known threads but which are potentially accessible from the API. That doesn't mean I am saying that the issue is in this library – it just enlarges the area where to search for. Your code doesn't seem to make efforts to check for thread-safety, too.